# MATLABs strrep function with overlapping search results

Tags: matlab

MATLABs `strrep` is doing things differently than I was expecting it:

```
strrep('ababab', 'bab', 'bbb')
```

I would hope that the strings are replaced incrementally, thus first `abbbab` and than `abbbbb`. However, MATLAB returns `abbbbbb` (Note the additional, 6th `b` at the end).

What is MATLAB doing under the hood? Finding the indices and then inserting the new string at each index? Something totally different?

And, most importantly, how may I archive the intended result?

---

To be precise, the example above is just the minimal example to reduce additional sources of errors. In real world I would like to replace sequences in integer vectors:

```
strrep([1 0 1 0 1 0],  [0  1 0], [0 0 0])
```

and get

```
1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[Matlab's documentation for `strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) tells you what you need to know. From the tips section at the the bottom of the page:

> Before replacing strings, strrep finds all instances of oldSubstr in origStr, like the strfind function. For overlapping patterns, strrep performs multiple replacements. See the final example in the Examples section.

The last example compares the behavior of `strrep` and `regexprep`. I think [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) will do what you want on a string. To work on numbers, you could convert to a string using `char(vector)`, run `regexprep` on that, and then convert back to numbers using `double(string)`.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `doc strrep` - I always forget that there is more than in `help ...`. However, `regexprep` for my string example returns `abbbab`, the integer example does not work at all. Thus, only my first question is answered yet.